# Get filenames using glob

Tags: python, filenames, glob

I am reading several tsd files using panda and combine them to a big frame. I am using glob to iterate trough all the files in my directory and sub-directories. Every single frame gets a unique key. Now I want to create a reference table where the file name to each key is stored. But since I don't really understand glob I don't know how to get only the names of the files.

```
p = Path('myPath')
data = []
reference_table = {}
number_of_files = 0

for tsd_files in p.glob('**/*.tsd'):
        data.append(pd.read_csv(str(tsd_files), delim_whitespace=True, header=None))
        number_of_files = number_of_files + 1

whole_data = pd.concat(data, keys= list(range(number_of_files)))
```

Comment: Use `os.path.basename` on the full pathname to get the filename.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `os.path.basename()` to get only filename from path.

```
p = Path('myPath')
data = []
reference_table = {}
number_of_files = 0
file_names = []

for tsd_files in p.glob('**/*.tsd'):
    data.append(pd.read_csv(str(tsd_files), delim_whitespace=True, header=None))
    number_of_files = number_of_files + 1
    file_names.append(os.path.basename(tsd_files))

whole_data = pd.concat(data, keys= list(range(number_of_files)))
```

Comment: thanks. I knew there has to be an easy way like that but I couldn't find it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's use `Path` in a pythonic way.

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('dir')
filenames = [i.stem for i in p.glob('**/*.ext')]
```

`p.glob('**/*.ext')` returns a generator object, which needed be iterated to get it values out, which done wit [i for i in ..]

`i.stem` means filenames with extentions.